# May "self-taught" and "self-study" be written without hyphen?

Tags: hyphens

> I am a self-taught learner, so I mostly read the self-study books.

May self-taught and self-study be written without hyphens?

Comment: The term "self-study" is not normal use.  Better is, "I am a self-taught learner, so I mostly study books on my own."

Comment: self-study course

Answer (score 1):

Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective.

> an off-campus apartment
>
> state-of-the-art design

When a compound adjective follows a noun, a hyphen is usually not necessary.

> The apartment is off campus.

However, some established compound adjectives are always hyphenated. Double-check with a dictionary or online.

> The design is state-of-the-art.

According to the Concise Oxford Dictionary, **self-** is a hyphenated prefix, so **self-taught** and **self-study** are always hyphenated. This seems to be the usual practice according to [google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=self-study%2Cself%20study&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cself%20-%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cself%20study%3B%2Cc0)

You may find these [guidelines for hyphenation](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp) useful.